# JSON no me devuelve una imagen

Tags: json, imagen

estoy recorriendo un array de JSON con js. Me toma todos los datos de manera correcta, pero a la hora de devolver las imágenes solo me pone la ruta en txt y no las imágenes en sí

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes, recomiendo que realices el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y así también ganes tu primera medalla!. También lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Recuerda que si necesitas ayuda con la depuración del código debes de proveer un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pues nosotros no somos adivinos para saber cual es el código que usas. Usa el enlace de [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/477944/edit) para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta.

Comment: Las imagenes no vienen fisicamente dentro del json, viene la ruta como te sucede a ti. Esa ruta debes ponerla luego en el atributo src de una etiqueta img (html) para poder visualizarla en el navegador